# mead-halls; wood-shafted; bronze-hilted; iron-edged; bog-iron

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

Structures and meanings of the bolded phrases in the following short passage?

> The Beowulf warriors have a foot in both the Bronze and Iron Ages.
>   Their **mead-halls** reflect the wealthy living of the Bronze Age
>   Northmen, and their wooden shields, **wood-shafted** spears, and
>   **bronze-hilted** swords are those of the Bronze Age warrior. However,
>   they carry **iron-tipped** spears, and their best swords have iron or
>   **iron-edged** blades. Beowulf also orders an iron shield for his fight
>   with a dragon. Iron replaced bronze because it produced a blade with a
>   cutting edge that was stronger and sharper. The Northmen learned how
>   to forge iron in about 500 B.C. Although they had been superior to the
>   European Celts in bronze work, it was the Celts who taught them how to
>   make and design iron work. Iron was accessible everywhere in
>   Scandinavia, usually in the form of "**bog-iron**" found in the layers of
>   peat in peat bogs.

Comment: Have you looked any of these up?

Comment: @userr2684291 yes I looked up. E.g: about "shaft" verb there has been written "to treat someone very unfairly, especially by dishonestly getting money from them"

Comment: @M.Afrashteh: It also means "to fit with a shaft", which is the long part of a spear (or of other things). Whether this meaning leads to the one about treating someone unfairly is debated, and the logic for it is... unpleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Mead-halls*** and ***bog-iron*** are two nouns joined together by a hyphen, which is a way that people sometimes express what might be expressed without a hyphen. The first noun is acting in an *attributive* way on the second. Thus a mead-hall is a hall for mead (i.e. for drinking, particularly for major celebrations which would be when the relatively expensive mead would be used), and bog-iron is iron found in bogs. Both expressions also exist without the hyphen, and in the case of mead-hall it's occasionally attested as a single word, meadhall. The combined expression, whether there's a space, a hyphen, or just as a single word, is that they act as a noun phrase.

***Wood-shafted*** and the others are a noun and a past participle, and the meaning in these cases would be "shafted with wood". Or you can understand it as two nouns again, but with the second transformed into a participle - in all these examples, the meanings are the same. Thus the spears have wooden shafts, swords have bronze hilts, blades have iron edges and spears have iron tips. In all cases, this compound ends up acting as an adjective.

Both structures can be used for new coinages, but as always I would caution any language learner from being too free with coining new terms - you may be saying something there is already a word for, but you just don't know it yet. Also, a lack of deep experience with the language means you can't tell whether something is going to sound weird, make sense, or be completely unnatural.

Answer (score 2):

These are all words joined with a hyphen to form either *compound nouns* or *compound adjectives*. You won't find them in dictionaries the way that true compound words (eg "flowerpot") are, but you could certainly have looked up the individual words to understand them.

A **mead-hall** is a *hall* (a function room) where *mead* (an ancient alcoholic drink brewed from honey) is served.

A **wood-shafted** spear would be a spear with a *shaft* made of *wood*.

A **bronze-hilted** sword would be a sword with a *hilt* made of *bronze*.

An **iron-edged** blade would be a *blade* with edges made of iron.

**Bog-iron** shouldn't even need an explanation, as it is explained in the text:

> Iron was accessible everywhere in Scandinavia, usually in the form of "bog-iron" found in the layers of peat in peat bogs.

So it is *iron* found in *bogs*.